# Converting an SVN repository to SQL database

Tags: oracle

I have downloaded the svn repository of Atunes using TortoiseSVN. I would like to transfer the logs of activity of the developers to a SQL database, preferably an Oracle one. Is there any software that can help me do this?

Comment: Is this an XY problem?  You want to do X, and you think Y is the best way of doing so. Instead of asking about X, you ask about Y. http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341

Answer (score 1):

The command line SVN client can export the log to an XML file with the --xml option.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get complete repository of subversion. Tortoise svn do not have this option right now. I think you only checked out latest revision.  You need to use other programs to get complete repository with all history for example: svk (http://svk.bestpractical.com/view/HomePage).

Subversion uses two backends.

1. File based
2. Berkeley DB based.

Create your new repository Berkeley Db Based and get all history using a tool. 
After that since Berkeley DB 
(http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/berkeley-db/index.html)
Oracle supported one, you can migrate to Oracle.

But in my opinion this is all hard work. If all you need some statistics from subversion other tools exists for this purpose.